# TPC - Identity primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I am using code first (EntityFramework 6.1) with a Table Per Concrete type approach.

According to the very last comment of this [thread](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2133), EF 6.1 does not set the SQL auto-increment `Identity` *on*. I understand that.

But I want to force this `Identity` *on* since I will never use (nor define) the base class `DbSet<>`. I will not access the base class collection, only the concrete ones.

More that words, some code:

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] // <- tried to force it, but does not work
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] DataVersion { get; set; }

    public string CreatedWho { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedWhen { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedWho { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedWhen { get; set; }
}

public class Currency : BaseModel
{
    public string IsoCode {get; set; }
}
```

In My `DbContext` class there is:

```
public DbSet<Currency> Currencies {get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Enable TPC Inheritance
    modelBuilder.Entity<Currency>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable(typeof(Currency).Name);
        });

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

With this code, in my generated DB Table `Currency`, I have all the `BaseModel` columns as expected, `Id` is the Primary Key, ok. But it does not have the `Identity` property set *on*, despite the explicite `DatabaseGenerated` attribute usage.

How can I force the `Identity` in a TPC inheritance schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` works finally to force the Identity behaviour on my PK in a TPC inhertiance context.

The trick? Package Console commande `Update-Databse -Force` does **not** apply changes of that sort automatically. You need to remove your Tables to recreate them all fresh.

I use the following SQL script to remove everything (even `__MigrationHistory`), inspired from [this blog](http://edspencer.me.uk/2013/02/25/drop-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-database-azure-friendly/) :

```
WHILE ( EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                 FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
                 WHERE  CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' ) )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(2000)
        SELECT TOP 1
                @sql = ( 'ALTER TABLE ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.[' + TABLE_NAME
                         + '] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + CONSTRAINT_NAME + ']' )
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
        WHERE   CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
        EXEC (@sql)
        PRINT @sql
    END
GO 

WHILE ( EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                 FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ) )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(2000)
        SELECT TOP 1
                @sql = ( 'DROP TABLE ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.[' + TABLE_NAME
                         + ']' )
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

        EXEC (@sql)
        PRINT @sql
    END
```

After that, re-run the `Update-Database -Force` command to regenerate all tables. `Identity` will be activated.

Comment: As part of a DB update strategy, you could also copy the content of your existing tables to temporary tables, run the SQL DDL above to drop the existing ones (except the temp tables), recreate them with your new table schema and insert the data from the temporary tables back in before dropping the temporary tables.

Comment: Sidenote.. This wont work if you have multiple classes that inherits from the same baseclass, (they all share the same pk identity, resulting in duplicated pks). The only solution for this as far as i know is to put different seeds for each derived class...

Answer (score 1):

Identity columns are per table, with TPC you have a table per class, and no shared base class table that will hold the identity generated id. If you have the concrete type table generate identity as an id, you will get duplicate ids across these tables.

A discussion of this issue can be found e.g. [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines), with this part covering this specific issue:

> **How to Solve The Identity Problem in TPC**
>
> As you saw, using SQL Server’s int identity columns doesn't work very
>   well together with TPC since there will be duplicate entity keys when
>   inserting in subclasses tables with all having the same identity seed.
>   Therefore, to solve this, either a spread seed (where each table has
>   its own initial seed value) will be needed, or a mechanism other than
>   SQL Server’s int identity should be used. Some other RDBMSes have
>   other mechanisms allowing a sequence (identity) to be shared by
>   multiple tables, and something similar can be achieved with GUID keys
>   in SQL Server. While using GUID keys, or int identity keys with
>   different starting seeds will solve the problem but yet another
>   solution would be to completely switch off identity on the primary key
>   property. As a result, we need to take the responsibility of providing
>   unique keys when inserting records to the database. We will go with
>   this solution since it works regardless of which database engine is
>   used.

Comment: I get that. But is there any possibility to force the Identity *on* (which is not the default behaviour since 6.1)?

Comment: @Askolein You could try (1) `HasDatabaseGenerationOption(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity)` in the mapping, but I suspect it will be ignored just like the attribute or (2) specifiying/overriding/augmenting the SQL DDL for the tables by hand in a custom DBInitializer. But this could have side effects.

Comment: I tried via fluent configuration. As you expected: ignored too.